# Is dynamic linq suitable for this scenario?

Tags: c#, linq, interface, dynamic-linq

I have a simple interface, IDevice

```
public interface IDevice{
    string Id{ get; }
}
```

I have a list of objects that implement `IDevice`

```
List<IDevice> devices;
```

An example of two of the types of objects in this list are:

```
public class BatteryDevice : IDevice{
    public string Id{ get; private set; }
    public int StateOfCharge{ get; set; }
}

public class GridDevice : IDevice{
    public string Id{ get; private set; }
    public decimal Voltage{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to allow the user to set a condition in text using a SQL query like this:

```
Id = 'Battery1' AND StateOfCharge > 95
```

So that I can read these conditions from a text config file and evaluate against the list of devices using dynamic LINQ like this:

```
var matches = devices.Where("Id = 'Battery1' AND StateOfCharge > 95");
```

This doesn't work because (of course) the LINQ would fail when trying to get a value for `StateOfCharge` from the `GridDevice`

I'm feeling like a bit of a n00b and looking for a way to achieve my goal and would appreciate any input.

Comment: Will the user write this 'Id = 'Battery1' AND StateOfCharge > 95' in text? or you will get the values from 2 separate inputs?

Comment: Might need to cast first  `devices.OfType<BatteryDevice>().Where(...`

Comment: @AmrElgarhy I was hoping to allow them to enter it as a single line of text, the idea being that a bunch of SwitchDevices could be turned on or off by evaluating the SQL condition string

Comment: @Jimbo using the devices (IDevice) to query will not work for both inherited classes except if you inserted a cast in your query something like what Olivier Rogier answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
var matches = devices
              .OfType<BatteryDevice>()
              .Where(device => device.Id == "Battery1" && device.StateOfCharge > 95)
              .ToList();
```

It selects all devices from the `List` of `IDevice` of type `BatteryDevice` having matching desired condition and returns a `List<BatteryDevice>` having items of the resulting Linq query sequence.

You can use `ToList` or not depending of what you plan to do with the result.

If not the result is type of `IEnumerable<BatteryDevice>`.

To have a `List` of `IDevice` you can use:

```
.ToList<IDevice>();
```

Or you can write:

```
var matches = (IEnumerable<IDevice>)devices...
```

**Without Linq**

```
var matches = new List<IDevice>();
foreach ( var device in devices )
  if ( device is BatteryDevice )
  {
    var battery = (BatteryDevice)device;
    if ( battery.Id == "Battery1" && battery.StateOfCharge > 95 )
      matches.Add(battery);
  }
```

Comment: Points for `.OfType<T>` :) Makes me wonder though, if Im not coming at the problem from the wrong angle?

Comment: Your design seems to be correct but without polymorphism nor inheritence that you simulate by using an interface and you repeat code, so what wrong angle about what problem?

Comment: Thanks. Given there will be many different types that implement IDevice e.g. inverters, chargers, temperature sensors, humidity sensors, weather sensor, time sensor, I will need to create a ForLoop which enumerates all the types in the assembly that implement IDevice, then filter the device list and run the query on each. May not be performant, which is why Im wondering if there is a better way of doing this given I'd like to read the query from text config file.

Comment: I don't think, as I know. OfType is convenient. You can if course use a loop and check the type for each items then cast and apply the test. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think still you can use dynamic Linq or Linq. Just check type first.

Sure this can't work. not type safe.

```cs
var filter1 = devices.Where(q => (q as GridDevice).Voltage == 0);
```

This will be work because first filter is check Type. You wont get object ref error.

```cs
var filtered=devices.Where(q => q.GetType() == typeof(GridDevice) && (q as GridDevice).Voltage==0);
```

Comment: Interested to know if that can be written in dynamic LINQ? i.e. text rather than expression.